# How to Run Anaconda as admin on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

## When I run the following code in Jupyter Notebook on my Mac

```
import keyboard
if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    print("Yes")
```

## It shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mayankmalviya64/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/mayankmalviya64/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/mayankmalviya64/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 294, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Users/mayankmalviya64/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 430, in listen
    raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator
```

Since on MacOS, run as administrator option is NOT available like Windows, what should I do ?
I want to detect keypress like when any-key on the keyboard is pressed, the program stops !!

```
I have also tried to run the above code through my terminal in iPython. It shows the same error there too.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open it using the terminal with this command

```
sudo open /Users/<your-username>/Applications/Anaconda
```

Use the proper directory if you changed

Comment: It is showing "Anaconda Navigator cannot be opened with root access privileges !!"

Comment: Just google this error and your going to find a bunch of answers in Stackoverflow. In generate sudo open is the way to force open an app as root.

Comment: I tried this way infact I have gone through most of them but most of the problems which relate to this one are either unsolved or ultimately end up to the same question I have asked above !!

Comment: The actual question is a different matter than the title.